# Auto-print Chapter Number

Tags: chapters, counters, tufte

In the `\documentclass{tufte-book}`

The normal header for Chapter would be

```
\chapter{6}
```

etc. But how can I get the chapter number to display as an auto counter, without having to fill in that actual number. I know that chapter has a counter already associated with it, but if you just leave the brackets empty it obviously doesn't print the chapter number.

(I'm moving chapters around so want to have the counter display without having to change the whole string of chapter numbers every time a chapter gets broken apart. as far as I understand, I can't put a command inside the brackets like

```
\chapter{\counter}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit after @DavidCarlisle's comment about refstepcounter:

```
\newcounter{mychapter}

\newcommand{\aasc}{\refstepcounter{mychapter}\let\newtitle\themychapter}
\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]
{%
\aasc%
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{}=0
\chapter{\newtitle.}%
\else
\chapter{\newtitle.\space #1}%
\fi
}
```

It works with labels and refs now... Thanks @DavidCarlisle...

**OldAnswer**

Try this in your preamble:

```
\newcommand{\aasc}{\addtocounter{chapter}{1}\let\newtitle\thechapter}
\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]
{
\aasc
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{}=0
\chapter{\newtitle.}
\else
\chapter{\newtitle.\space #1}
\fi
}
```

It works for empty or non-empty chapters... but empty has to not contain even a space...

Comment: it would be better to use `\restepcounter{chapter}` so you can use `\label`, rather than `\addtocounter{chapter}{1}`

Comment: thanks @DavidCarlisle... checking your command... I thought it was \stepcounter...

Comment: no `\stepcounter` would just do the same as you have, you want `\refstepcounter` (you are also missing several `%` from ends of lines)

Comment: why the newcounter?

Comment: because in his original document type the chapter does not provides or stepping the chapter counter and I don't want to come across unexpected problems with definitions etc

Comment: well actually the `chapter` counter is defined by the class (see my answer)  but OK, I just thought that you had changed it because you had switched from `\addtocounter` to `\refstepcounter` but that was an unrelated change, OK.

Comment: You did it the easy way in your answer :)... upvoted
Also, I think that the % missing from my code does not provide any difference because chapter always uses a \par (mot sure for that) but I will fix it because it is a bad programming practice

Comment: If you pushed me I could generate an example where the missing `%` causes a blank page:-)

Answer (score 4):

The argument to `\chapter` is intended to be the *title* not a number. As in most classes chapters are numbered automatically.

However the tufte class sets section numbering off by the default as part of its style, you can allow chapters and sections to be numbered by setting

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
```

However the design is really based around unnumbered headings so an alternative would be to use a class designed for numbered headings. However with the above line, you get

[image]

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Intro}
\section{zzzz}
zzzz
\chapter{Something}
\section{zzzz}
zzzz

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use {secnumdepth} and set it to start at 0, not 1? i.e. a chapter 0 

(I know I can supress the number with the *, but I don't want just an unnumbered chapter, but specifically 0)

Comment: `\setcounter{chapter}{-1}` anywhere before the first chapter

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

Use the package `cleveref` and in the preamble you can customize your referencing as you wish. For me I use the following customization for chapters:

```
\crefname{chapter}{Chapter}{Chapters}
\Crefname{chapter}{Chapter}{Chapters}
\crefformat{chapter}{Chapter #1}
\crefrangeformat{chapter}{#1}
```

Note that you can replace `Chapter` and `Chapters` with abbreviated forms such as `Ch`. You can also further customize the numbering by adding a dot like `\crefformat{chapter}{Chapter. #1}` or brackets like `\crefformat{chapter}{Chapter. (#1)}` which will automatically put brackets for chapter numbers. Here is a sample code:

```
\documentclass[]{report}


\usepackage{cleveref}

% Define formats
\crefname{chapter}{Chapter}{Chapters}
\Crefname{chapter}{Chapter}{Chapters}
\crefformat{chapter}{Chapter #1}
\crefrangeformat{chapter}{#1}



\begin{document}



\chapter{First Chapter}
\label{ch:first}
For more information about this topic please refer to \cref{ch:fifth,,ch:third,,ch:fourth}


\chapter{Second Chapter}
\label{ch:second}
In \cref{ch:first}, we introduced (topic name). Here, we address the problem in more detail.


\chapter{Third Chapter}
\label{ch:third}


\chapter{Fourth Chapter}
\label{ch:fourth}


\chapter{Fifth Chapter}
\label{ch:fifth}



\end{document}
```

The beauty of `\cref` command is that it handles the order of referenced chapters, sections, or floats automatically. For instance, I deliberately wrote `\cref{ch:fifth,,ch:third,,ch:fourth}` where the fifth chapter is put first in the referencing, but still, `\cref` shows them in their order of appearance after you compile the document.

Comment: you have not used the `tufte-book` class though, which is the point of the question (as it does not number chapters by default)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It also seems that he does not know how to reference chapters systematically:

"I'm moving chapters around so want to have the counter display without having to change the whole string of chapter numbers every time a chapter gets broken apart."